# unresolved reference error for 'require'

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have created a simple javascript web app using webpack. I get the unresolved reference error for 'require' in my console when I try to run my app. Here are my files:

main.js:

```
require('./logger');
const name = 'Scotch.io';
setTimeout(() => alert(`Hello there from ${name}`), 1);
```

logger.js:

```
let checkName= (firstName, lastName) => {
    if(firstName !== 'nader' || lastName !== 'dabit') {
        console.log('You are not Nader Dabit');
    } else {
        console.log('You are Nader Dabit');
    }
}
checkName('nader', 'jackson');
```

Web pack config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: ["./global.js" , "./main.js"],
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.es6$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
     },
     resolve: {
         extensions: ['', '.js', '.es6']
    },
}
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You simply stated `require('./logger')`.

This is the problem. You need to assign it to a variable.

Like this:

```
var logger = require('./logger')
```

**BTW**, require does not work on the client side (in-browser), it only works on the server side with the NodeJS framework.

Comment: How am I supposed to import dependencies then?